# VBscript problem : how to end if vercode is not equal to 1234

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VBscript, so I need help with the following. As you notice on line 12, vercode is mentioned. I want a statement there saying that if vercode is not "1234" nothing else will help (ie scripts terminate). Do you know how?

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!-- #INCLUDE file="inc/settings.asp" -->
<!-- #INCLUDE file="inc/functions.asp" -->
<!-- #INCLUDE file="inc/db_connect.asp" -->
<%
nameSurname = sqlquote(trim(request.form("name"))) & ""
comment = sqlquote(trim(request.form("comment")) & "")
nid = request.form("nid")
pid = request.form("pid")
comment_date = DatePart("d",now()) & "/" & DatePart("m",now()) & "/" & DatePart("yyyy",now())

if vercode = "1234" then
if nameSurname = "" then nameSurname = "Anonymous" end if
if comment <> "" then 
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Comments (fName, Comment, DateSubmitted, NewsID) " &_
              "VALUES ('" & nameSurname & "', '" & comment & "', #" & comment_date & "#, " & nid & ");"
    con.execute strSQL
    con.close
end if
response.redirect("news.asp?NewsID=" & encrypt(nid) & "&PID=" & encrypt(pid) )
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of terminating the script if vercode is not "1234", you run the interesting part of your script if it is equal to "1234", like below:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!-- #INCLUDE file="inc/settings.asp" -->
<!-- #INCLUDE file="inc/functions.asp" -->
<!-- #INCLUDE file="inc/db_connect.asp" -->
<%
nameSurname = sqlquote(trim(request.form("name"))) & ""
comment = sqlquote(trim(request.form("comment")) & "")
nid = request.form("nid")
pid = request.form("pid")
comment_date = DatePart("d",now()) & "/" & DatePart("m",now()) & "/" & DatePart("yyyy",now())

if vercode = "1234" then
  if nameSurname = "" then 
    nameSurname = "Anonymous" 
  end if
  if comment <> "" then 
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Comments (fName, Comment, DateSubmitted, NewsID) " &_
                                        "VALUES ('" & nameSurname & "', '" & comment & "', #" & comment_date & "#, " & nid & ");"
                                        'debugging strsql
    con.execute strSQL
    con.close
  end if
  response.redirect("news.asp?NewsID=" & encrypt(nid) & "&PID=" & encrypt(pid) )
end if    
%>
```

Comment: I HAVE UPDATE THE WORDING AS JAY RIGGS HAS TOLD ME...... it still doesnt work. please help. 10x

Comment: I've updated my response based on some changes you made.  Try it out and if it doesn't work try to describe the problem